# I need help understanding notation from group theory articles and literature

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, lie-groups, vector-fields

I need help understanding the notation of this question. I have a general understanding of groups but I don't know what a left-translation map is.

**We will study the left-translation maps and left-invariant vector fields for two Lie group examples: R<sup>n</sup> (with vector addition as the group operation) and GL(*n*).**

**Given *v* ∈ R<sup>n</sup>, what is the corresponding left-translation map L<sub>*v*</sub> : R<sup>n</sup> → R<sup>n</sup>?**

I understand that R<sup>n</sup> is a Lie group. But what is *v*? Is it a transformation or group action? I'm not entirely sure what an element of a group actually is.

And could someone explain to me what **L<sub>*v*</sub> : R<sup>n</sup> → R<sup>n</sup>** is conveying? I see it all over literature and need a solid understanding of what it means to continue my reading. I also constantly see **μ: G × G → G**. Does this mean any operation on an element in G will map back to another element in G?

Thanks!

Comment: It's an element of $\mathbf{R}^n$, the $n$ dimensional vector space whose elements are $n$ tuples of real numbers, like you would have learned in any basic linear algebra course. It says so right in the quote... $L_v$ is the map from basic group theory that "multiplies" (in this case, adds because the operation in the group is addition) $v$ on the left. So $L_v(x) = v+x$ (vector addition) in this instance.

Comment: Presumably $\mu: G \times G \to G$ is just the name of the group operation itself.

Answer (score 1):

$v$ is a group element, and $L_v$ denotes left multiplication by $v$. For the abelian group $\Bbb R^n$, we have $L_v(x) = v+x \ (=x+v)$. For the group $GL(n)$, $v$ is now an invertible matrix, and $L_v(A)=vA$.